# Instalando aplicación laravel + livewire - no encuentra los componentes

Tags: laravel-8

estoy tratando de subir a producción un sitio creado en Laravel que tiene componentes livewire en una estructura de carpetas creada para ordenar los componentes y mi problema es que en mi servidor de desarrollo, en local, todo funciona bien, pero al subirlo a producción, no me detecta las carpetas, les muestro como está definida la estructura de carpetas y que error me está tirando en mi intento de subida a producción.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y a continuación, les muestro el error que me está generando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, este es mi problema, si alguien me puede ayudar, estaré muy agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes listar las carpetas desde la consola de produccion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu raíz, la carpeta “Clientes” está con “C” y lo llamas con:

> "livewire.clientes.consuclientes",

Prueba cambiando la inicial de tus carpetas, porque las sub carpetas que se encuentran en:

> resources/views/livewire/...

Son todas minúsculas cuando se crean los componentes.